# Opening Google Search results for music in PowerAMP?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, music, search

Is it possible to have Google Search open music files via PowerAmp instead of the default player? I have tried to see if there is a default music player, but it's not set. Music is listed under "searchable" items, there is no way to add, but I would love to be able to quickly search for music via the Google Search on the phone.

Or is it possible to have Android Music (default player) not auto-search all music but create an index of specific directories? By defaults it will also include all call recordings and whatsapp voice messages. It would be enough to only have the music on sdcard/Music indexed.

Answer (score 1):

That's two questions in one -- it would have been better to separate them.

1. If you execute an action which has multiple apps as options -- such as e.g. tapping on a music file in your file explorer when having multiple players installed, Andoid initially asks you for the app to use -- and lets you chose to make it the default. Worked fine for me with the Cubed player. This requires the "additional" app has a corresponding "listener" established as PowerAmp does, in your case.

   - *After* an app has been selected as the default, you can easily reverse that choice. Look under **System Settings** / **Apps** / **All** (sweep tabs to the left, if **All** is not visible).
   - Select the **Clear defaults** button (near the bottom) on the **App info** page for the Android stock music player (**Google Play Music** in my case, unsure if that one is your Android *stock* player).
   - If it asks for confirmation, confirm **yes**.
   - The next time you search for and select a local audio file, you will then be offered the opportunity to choose your preferred player app (enable the **Use by default for this action** checkbox, if you wish).
2. You can exclude locations from being scanned by the media scanner by placing a file named `.nomedia` within those directories. The media scanner will then exclude this directory from its scan, and thus contained files will not make it into the library. You still can chose manually to play them by e.g. looking them up with a file explorer.